# Why redux store data change triggers component state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am struggling with this for a while now. I will try to describe it as simple as i can. I have two components. In first one (lets named it parent) i have a function that receives one parameter and it sets that parent component state with it. Also it does some action that changes data in redux store. Also i am watching for changes in component state, just to see when it changes. I need to call that function form other component (lets named it child) and pass parameter. Parameter is data from redux store that is changed with that function.

Parent component:

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => {
    const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState({});

    const doSomething = (user) => {
        setSelectedUser(user)
        changeReduxStore(user);
    }

   // check if selected user has changed

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log('data changed')
   }, [selectedUser])

   return(
       <ChildComponent handleClick={doSomething}/>
   )
}
```

Child component:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {

   return(
       <div onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.user)}/>Trigger click</div>
   )
}
```

The problem is that when I trigger that function, state selectedUser changes two times and console message 'data changed' writes down two times and it need just one. It looks like when function is trigger it sets parent component state and change redux store data and when data in redux store is changed, child component render (what is perfectly normal cause child component receive that data as props) and somehow while rendering changes state of parent component again, but it doesn't trigger that function again.

I already tried doing something like this but it also changes selectedUser two times.

```
 const ChildComponent = (props) => {

     const callFunction = () => {
         props.handleClick(props.user)
     }

     return(
        <div onClick={callFuncion}/>Trigger click</div>
     )
 }
```

Comment: `setState` is an async operation but if its in non-lifecycle method, it will trigger a render immediately. So you have 2 state (*component, redux*) updates resulting in 2 renders. Question thoug is, why do you need component state? That value is in store, so why not pull it from there?

Comment: When you are dispatching action and updating redux store, props are changing which is triggering the re-render. Use-effect will be called twice one for state change and one for redux props change in ParentComponent.

Comment: Also note, `setSelectedUser` is being called once. Your `useEffect` is being called twice which should not be that big of a deal

Comment: @Rajesh i didn't considered that setState is an async, i will try to restructure it a bit. I simplify it here, i also do something with that data so i can't just take it from store. useEffect is called three times. First time when component mount, and then when i click to trigger function another two times, but it shoud only once, cause i change state only once

Comment: @shubham-gupta but useEffect shoudnt trigger on redux props change cause i set dependency to trigger only when state is changed. Now it triggers when component mount, and when i click on that function it triggers two times, and it shoud only one

Comment: @bobby `useEffect` is replacement of `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. So, when props are changed, irrespective of the fact you are using it or not, it will be called. Question is why do you have same/similar data in component's state and in store?

Comment: @Rajesh in store i have users that i am fetching from server, child component is table that lists all that users,  every row in table is one user and it has some action buttons (delete, update, change status...) and when i click od that button i need to send that user to parent component and do something with it. I could done ti without setting it in stare, but when user is chose i alsp need to do some other stuff and i need to get iz somehow, so i am using state

Comment: @Rajesh and if u move setSelectedUser, console.log will trigger just once, if props change or not